# Modifying an reading big .txt file with MPI/c++?

Tags: c++, file, mpi

I am using MPI together with C++. I want to read information from one file, modify it by some rule, and then write modified content in the same file. I am using temporary file which where I store modified content and at the end I overwrite it by these commands:

```
temp_file.open("temporary.txt",ios::in);
ofstream output_file(output_name,ios::out);
output_file<<temp_file.rdbuf(); 
output_file.flush();
temp_file.close();
output_file.close();
remove("temporary.txt");
```

This function which modify the file is executed by MPI process with rank 0. After exiting from function, `MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);` is called to ensure synchronization.
And then, all MPI processes should read modified file and perform some computations. The problem is that, since file is too big, data are not completely written to file when execution of function is finished, and I get wrong results. I also tried to put `sleep()` command, but sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't (it depends on the node where I perform computations). Is there general way to solve this problem?
I put MPI as a tag, but I think this problm is inherently connected with c++ standard and manipulating with storage. How to deal with this latency between writing in buffer aand writing in file on storage medium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fun topic.  You are dealing with two or maybe three consistency semantics here.

POSIX consistency says essentially when a byte is written to a file, it's visible.

NFS consistency says "woah, that's way too hard.  you write to this file and I'll make it visible whenever I feel like it. "

MPI-IO consistency semantics (which you aren't using, but are good to know) say that data is visible after specific synchronization events occur.   Those two events are "close a file and reopen it" or "sync file, barrier, sync file again".

If you are using NFS, give up now.  NFS is horrible.  There are a lot of good parallel file systems you can use, several of which you can set up entirely in userspace (such as PVFS).

If you use MPI-IO here, you'll get more well-defined behavior, but the MPI-IO routines are more like C system calls than C++ iostream operators, so think more like open(2) read(2) write(2) and close(2).  Text files are usually a headache to deal with but in your case where modifications are appended to file, that shouldn't be too bad.